# using awk with variables in a shell script

Tags: tcsh

I have a file called "random" that looks like this:

```
A B C D
A B C D
A B C D
```

How can I get this shell script to print up the second column?

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh -f

set variable = "2"
awk '{print "$""'"$variable"'" }' random
```

It gives:

```
$2
$2
$2
$2
$2
```

if I hardcode $2 like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh -f

awk '{print $2 }' random
```

I get

```
B
B
B
```

But I need to set the value differently each time so hardcoding isn't an option

Comment: `tcsh` and `csh` are terrible for shell scripting. There are many inconsistencies that cannot really be coded around. I would most strongly recommend that you write scripts in `bash` or `sh` rather than `[t]csh`. (By all means leave your interactive sessions with `tcsh`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the variable to awk with awk's `-v` option.   e.g. to set the awk variable `n` to the same value as the csh variable `$variable`:

```
% set variable=2
% awk -v n="$variable" '{print $n}' random
B
B
B
```

Alternatively, pass the variable assignment as an argument after the script (awk will interpret arguments like `x=y` as an assignment, not as a filename):

```
% set variable=4
% awk '{print $n}' n="$variable" random
D
D
D
```

In both cases, the awk script will interpret `$n` as "the field numbered n"

Alternatively, you can use environment variables.  awk can access them through the `ENVIRON` array.  e.g.

```
% setenv variable 2
% awk '{print $ENVIRON["variable"]}' random
B
B
B
```

---

BTW, as others have mentioned in comments, `csh`/`tcsh` is not a good choice for a scripting language - use a bourne-like shell for shell scripting.  `tcsh` is still kind of OK-ish for an interactive shell, but doesn't offer anything that other shells don't already offer - csh was a superior interactive shell in the 1980s but other shells have long since surpassed it (and csh has the disadvantage of being different from a good scripting shell language, so you won't get experience with scripting just from interactive use of it).   Try switching to bash, ksh, or zsh instead.

Comment: second option worked, thanks.  regarding your third option, I get this error:  "setenv: Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters." Not quite sure why

Comment: all three options work. i tested them before posting.  the code-formatted sections are copy-pasted from tcsh in my terminal.

Comment: hey @cas I am 110% sure the error is on my end!  I was just curious if you might know why it might be happening.  But in any event your answer has helped me greatly - thank you.

Comment: i copy-pasted the wrong `setenv` line from my terminal.  should be `setenv variable 2` (without an `=` symbol). I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I remember all of (t)csh's quirks, but I think this works similarly to how it does in a POSIX-like shell. You have a quoted string `'{print "$""'`, including the double-quotes; then the quoted variable expansion `"$variable"`; then another quoted string `'" }'`. What awk gets is `{print "$""2" }`, there's two back-to-back awk strings, which awk concatenates. But they're strings, not the `$` operator.

```
awk '{print "$""'"$variable"'" }'
    <--quoted---><---var---><-q->
```

Lose the extra double-quotes:

```
tcsh> set variable = 2
tcsh> echo a b c | awk '{print $'"$variable"' }'
b
```

or in a POSIX-y shell:

```
$ variable=2
$ echo a b c | awk '{print $'"$variable"' }'
b
```